# `GLIBC_2.7' not found

Tags: linux, centos, centos5, glibc

I have fpcalc installed on Linux and when I execute the following command:

> ./fpcalc

I get an error saying:

```
./fpcalc: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by ./fpcalc)
```

I have tried googling around and I could not find a straight answer to fix this problem

I am running CentOS release 5.8 (Final) and glibc-2.5-81.el5_8.2 installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOS 5.x is based around GLIBC version 2.5. The version of fpcalc that you have is compiled against GLIBC 2.7. You will need to compile [fpcalc](http://acoustid.org/chromaprint/) against the C library available for your system.

The source code seems to be [available here](http://acoustid.org/chromaprint/).